# jquery <pre> debug collapse

Tags: php, jquery, pre

All time I use:

```
print'<pre>';
print_r($var);
print'</pre>';
```

to debug php.

I want to collapse this tree

```
[params] => JRegistry Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [show_title] => 
                                    [link_titles] => 
                                    [show_intro] =>
```

with jquery

Comment: you need to iterate over it with php and generate collapsable tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give Krumo a try - http://krumo.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

I use [Kint](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/) which is Excellent. To use it, just type :

```
// shows name of variable, collapsible value and place you called it from
d(varname); 
/* pretty stack trace that lets me expand the source, and see 
   the parameters passed to the function; same is achieved via `d(1);` */
Kint::trace()
```

Screenshot:

[image: Kint screenshot]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://kint-php.github.io/kint/))</sub>